# How to do polynomial transformations programmatically?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, math, polynomials

Suppose i have bunches of the below `n=36` polynomials/data:

[image]

They are all quite similar but with sightly different roof and amplitude, what is the best approach for me to code `a sequence of coefficients/changes` so that i can use this sequence to transform one polynomial to another one, say: `the blue one` + `a change sequence` -> `the green one`?

P.S.:

1. I had tried to use gaussian curve to fit the data, but unfortunately the results were very poor, so i have to use polynomials;
2. Currently the data are fitted by `numpy.polyfit(x, y, 35)`

---

Edit:

1. The intention is to find a way to generically describe the transformation between two polys, so i can use it to transform the future polys, say: in future i get a totally new poly like above, i can use this transformation code to transform it in a specific manner: increase/decrease the roof/amplitude, by specific manner i mean, note in the graph, the `y` changes around the roof x is always bigger, along `+x` / `-x` the changes are descending in a way, quite like gaussian curve, but unfortunately cannot use gaussian curve to express the data

Comment: You can choose one of the polynomials (a color) to be the base sequence, and then express all others by their difference in the coefficients. I.e. if the base sequence is blue, keep the `blue_coeffs` as returned by `np.polyfit` and set `green_coeffs_change = np.polyfit(green curve) - blue_coeffs`. The big question is, why would you want to do this?

Comment: @AlexP the intention is to use the change sequences to predict next poly, I think in this way the `green_coeffs_change` r quite specific to transform the blue one to green one, I am trying to find a way to generically express the coeffs changes so that I can use it to transform the future polys, say next input poly is a totally new one not in above graph, I still can code a coeffs change sequence to transform it a bit, like: increase/decrease the roof/amplitude in a similar manner, hope I make myself a bit more clear

Comment: Ok, this is becoming clearer, but it's still not the full picture. Your hypothetical model/transform that converts one curve to another will need some input. For simplicity, using your example, `a change sequence` will need to be a function of *something*, otherwise there is no way to know if the output should be e.g. the green or the red sequence. Some options for this *input* could be a) a point of the new data or b) the mean and std of the data. What do you plan on using?

Comment: @AlexP  the inputs r polys (sets of raw data yes, but guaranteed can be fitted like one of the above polys), the blocker to me is totally no idea how to construct the transformation sequence/function or whatever can do the transformation

Comment: The inputs cannot be polynomials. You have a given polynomial (say blue) and you want to "adapt" it to some other, unseen, data. How are these new data represented? If you are given each time the set of points for the new curve, then simply `polyfit` it to get the coefficients. If you are not given the new points, then what *are* you given?